# RegEx for ["abc", ["123", "cba"]]

Tags: java, regex

I'm not strong in regex, so any help would be appreciated.

I need to parse such strings:

```
["text", "text", ["text",["text"]],"text"]
```

And output should be (4 strings):

```
text, text, ["text",["text"]], text
```

I've tried this pattern `(\\[[^\\[,^\\]]*\\])|(\"([^\"]*)\")`:

```
String data="\"aa\", \"aaa\", [\"bb\", [\"1\",\"2\"]], [cc]";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(\\[[^\\[,^\\]]*\\])|(\"([^\"]*)\")");
```

But output is (quotes themselves in output are not so critical):

```
"aa", "aaa", "bb", "1", "2", [cc]
```

How to improve my regex?

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON? If so, there are libraries for Java that can do this.

Comment: @DelanAzabani unfortunately it's not JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately, this implicitly requires bracket matching (to make sure that you are matching the correct closing bracket), which can't be done with a regex in general. However, if you know that the brackets will be nested at most 2 or 3 levels, it is possible. Is this the case?

Comment: @dbaupp yes, at most 3 levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure regex are able to do that kind of stuff on their own. Here is a way to do it though:

```
// data string
String input = "\"aa\", \"a, aa\", [\"bb\", [\"1\", \"2\"]], [cc], [\"dd\", [\"5\"]]";
System.out.println(input);

// char that can't ever be within the data string
char tempReplacement = '#';
// escape strings containing commas, e.g "hello, world", ["x, y", 42]
while(input.matches(".*\"[^\"\\[\\]]+,[^\"\\[\\]]+\".*")) {
    input = input.replaceAll("(\"[^\"\\[\\]]+),([^\"\\[\\]]+\")", "$1" + tempReplacement + "$2");
}
// while there are "[*,*]" substrings
while(input.matches(".*\\[[^\\]]+,[^\\]]+\\].*")) {
    // replace the nested "," chars by the replacement char
    input = input.replaceAll("(\\[[^\\]]+),([^\\]]+\\])", "$1" + tempReplacement + "$2");
}

// split the string by the remaining "," (i.e. those non nested)
String[] split = input.split(",");

List<String> output = new LinkedList<String>();
for(String s : split) {
    // replace all the replacement chars by a ","
    s = s.replaceAll(tempReplacement + "", ",");
    s = s.trim();
    output.add(s);
}

// syso
System.out.println("SPLIT:");
for(String s : output) {
    System.out.println("\t" + s);
}
```

Output:

```
"aa", "a, aa", ["bb", ["1", "2"]], [cc], ["dd", ["5"]]
SPLIT:
    "aa"
    "a, aa"
    ["bb", ["1","2"]]
    [cc]
    ["dd", ["5"]]
```

PS: the code seems complex 'cause commented. Here is a more concise version:

```
public static List<String> split(String input, char tempReplacement) {
    while(input.matches(".*\"[^\"\\[\\]]+,[^\"\\[\\]]+\".*")) {
        input = input.replaceAll("(\"[^\"\\[\\]]+),([^\"\\[\\]]+\")", "$1" + tempReplacement + "$2");
    }
    while(input.matches(".*\\[[^\\]]+,[^\\]]+\\].*")) {
        input = input.replaceAll("(\\[[^\\]]+),([^\\]]+\\])", "$1" + tempReplacement + "$2");
    }
    String[] split = input.split(",");
    List<String> output = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(String s : split) {
        output.add(s.replaceAll(tempReplacement + "", ",").trim());
    }
    return output;
}
```

Call:

```
String input = "\"aa\", \"a, aa\", [\"bb\", [\"1\", \"2\"]], [cc], [\"dd\", [\"5\"]]";
List<String> output = split(input, '#');
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it's works perfect! But ther is one thing, that I forgot to say. What if there will be field like that: "text, with, comma"? How to replace comma nested in quotes too?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have recursion in your input, so if you have many nested `[]` regexes are probably not the best solution.

For this purpose I think it's far better/easier to use simple algorithm using `indexOf()` and `substring()`. It's also aften more efficient!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately i don't think you can do that with Java regexes. What you have here is recursive expression.. This type of language is not amendable to basic regular expressions (which is what java `Pattern` actually is).

But it's not that hard to write a small recursive descent parser for that language.

You can check to following answer for inspiration: [java method for parsing nested expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251781/java-method-for-parsing-nested-expressions)